Why does Air Force Two lack a tail number?
Some people have been claiming photo manipulation on shots of a recent political event in Detroit. I don't believe the claims, but one thing was brought up that was confusing: The C-32A (I assume) that's serving as Air Force Two at this event doesn't appear to have a tail number.
This is a screenshot from a video posted by an attendee at the event.

I would have expected to see the tail number there, as seen here:

I know they built 4 C-32As, and I assume they're all still in service as Air Force Two, but I would have expected all of them to have the tail number on both sides of the tail. I thought that was a legal requirement. Anyone know what's going on?

 US Air Mobility Command Has Ordered The Removal Of Numerous Tail Numbers In Recent Years
Air Force One and Air Force Two are both included in the order which otherwise involves cargo and refueling aircraft.
The reasoning given by USAMC is operational security.

Amazing. Bad guys telling apart the two VC-25 Air Force One planes was literally the plot of the pilot episode of NCIS.  20 years later…

How do these show on flight traffic displays as a type class or flight number for the specific duration of an operation, a random number?
